# How to add javascript code in every page?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

I want to use "Google Analytics" in website.

Now I configured my Google  Analytics. But at last it tell me that "This is your tracking code. Copy and paste it into the code of every page you want to track."

The given code is :

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-42279086-1', 'xyz.in');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I have already uploaded my website now How can I do that, any idea ?

I need this solution for java,.net & php language and also for wordpress  blog pls tell me if you know.

References  :

http://www.google.co.in/analytics/learn/setupchecklist.html

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en&utm_medium=et&utm_campaign=en_us&utm_source=SetupChecklist

Comment: I already know that we can add this javascript code using MasterPage .
Answer me any suggestion another than Master Page or templates..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save this script as a file and link it to every document, like this:

```
<script src="path_to_file.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution: install the [Google analytics plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/) and put the tracking key `UA-42279086-1` in its configuration.

A slightly more involved solution: paste the `<script>` tag into the template you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your wordpress setup per-se, but if you have the ability to edit the template itself, you can just paste that at the bottom.  Or, if you can add a block of arbitrary HTML to every page, then you can paste it there and add it to the footer of every page.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code just before the closing head tag in your header.php file for WordPress and for PHP sites I suggest you create a header.php file anyway and place all your head and HTML header divs & navigation etc in it then include on other pages with an include function